# Error while trying to use tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter notebook on a server which has tensorflow installed. The server runs ubuntu 16.04 and I activate the tensorflow environment by running

```
source /usr/local/tensorflow−python3/bin/activate
```

I am able to use tensorflow through the ipython3 shell but not when I am in the notebook file. I get an error saying that the tensorflow module is not found when I try to import it.

I had thought that this might be due to a mismatch in the python versions being used, but the result of executing the following commands is exactly the same in both the ipython3 shell and the notebook ...

```
import sys
sys.version
sys.executable
sys.path
```

It is a mystery to me why one of them is able to find the tf module while the other isn't. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: have you installed tensorflow in virtual environment or not? and did you choose the right kernel in notebook?

Comment: The `ipython shell` and `notebook` might be running the same python executable but you might not necessarily be in the same environment. Are you on any specific distribution?